# how to update the refreshToken on page refresh in next-auth?

Tags: authentication, next.js, next-auth, refresh-token

#### Summary

I have implemented `next-auth` to get the `accessToken` from the provider and pass the same as argument to my mutation, then use the token generated from our backend on consecutive API calls.

The token rotation has been implemented based on the next-auth doc [refresh token rotation](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/refresh-token-rotation)

#### Problem

After 1 min (my token expiry time) if the session is untouched/running in background then probably it calls the api and updates with the new `refreshToken` (works as intended) but when we refresh/reload the page after one minute it signs out of the session.

When I check the terminal, it looks like when I reload the page, the old refreshToken is not getting updated with new refreshToken. It still has the same refreshToken (the one session had before reload) in client but no the issue when we leave the app untouched

Is there any work around for this? Or what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

#### Snippet

here's the `pages/api/[..nextauth].tsx`

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt"
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github"
import { Provider, RefreshToken } from "../../../generated/graphql"

const loginQuery = `mutation login($AccessToken: String!, $Provider: Provider!) {
  login(accessToken: $AccessToken, provider: $Provider) {
    refreshToken
    token
    tokenExpiry
  }
}`

const refreshTokenQuery = `mutation refreshToken($RefreshToken: String!) {
  refreshToken(refreshToken: $RefreshToken) {
    refreshToken
    token
    tokenExpiry
  }
}`
const authMutation = (query, variables) : Promise<RefreshToken | null> => {
  return fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: query,
      variables: variables
    })
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.errors) {
        return null;
      } else {
        let response = data.data.refreshToken || data.data.login;
        if (response.refreshToken === undefined || 
        response.tokenExpiry === undefined || 
        response.token === undefined) return null
        return <RefreshToken> response;
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      return null;
    });
};

async function login(account, user: any) {
  let provider: Provider;
  if (account?.provider === 'github') provider = Provider.GitHub  
  if(provider === undefined) return
  const variables = {
    AccessToken: account.access_token,
    Provider: provider
  };
  const response = await authMutation(loginQuery, variables)
  if (response === null) return 
  console.log("new refresh token..", response.refreshToken)
  return {
    accessToken: response.token,
    accessTokenExpires: response.tokenExpiry * 1000,
    refreshToken: response.refreshToken,
    user,
  }
}

async function refreshAccessToken(token: any) {
  const variables = {
    RefreshToken: token.refreshToken,
  };
  console.log("variables", variables)
  const response = await authMutation(refreshTokenQuery, variables)
  if (response === null) return 
  console.log("new refresh token..", response.refreshToken)
  return {
    ...token,
    accessToken: response.token,
    accessTokenExpires: response.tokenExpiry * 1000,
    refreshToken: response.refreshToken,
  }
}

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GITHUB_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GITHUB_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  theme: {
    colorScheme: "light",
  },
  callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ account, token, user }: any): Promise<JWT> => {
      console.log("current refreshToken", token.refreshToken, token.accessTokenExpires)
       // Initial Sign In
      if (account && user) {
        console.log("initial login", account)
        return login(account, user) 
      }
      
       // Return previous token if the access token has not expired yet
      if (Date.now() < token.accessTokenExpires){
        console.log("token not expired")
        return token
      }

      // Rotate refresh_token and fetch new access_token if current one is expired
      if (token){
        console.log("token expired")
        return refreshAccessToken(token) 
      }
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }: any) => {
      if (!session?.user || !token?.accessToken) return
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken as string
      session.error = token.error as string | undefined
      session.user = token.user
      return session
    },
  },
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

and this how `_app.tsx` looks like,

```
import "../styles/globals.css"
import { SessionProvider as NextSessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"
import UrqlProvider from "../lib/provider"
import { AppProps } from "next/app"

function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

  const { session } = pageProps

  return (
    <>
      <NextSessionProvider session={session}>
        <UrqlProvider>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </UrqlProvider>
      </NextSessionProvider>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: i have the same issue, have you found any solutions? when i regenerate a new access token, and i refresh the page, the token is the old one and it's not updated.

Comment: It's an issue from `next-auth` and there wasn't any work around either, so we moved to super tokens: https://supertokens.com/

Super tokens works similar to `next-auth` and saves lots of time. Hope you find it useful and happy coding!

Comment: I resolved my issue using `redis` and `redlock` workaround, I followed these steps, [git gub issue link](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/3940#discussioncomment-2165231), I did have to refactor some of it based on my need, but it works, just in case anyone ever came upon this comment.